# Isothermal process

Tags: physical-chemistry

Internal energy is made up of the potential and kinetic energies,explain in molecular terms why the change in the internal energy of an ideal gas as the volume changes at constant temperature is always zero.

Comment: How do you think temperature and internal  energy are related? You need to show your own  attempt and reasoning.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 2):

The internal energy of an ideal gas does not depend on the volume at all. This is because there are no attractive forces between particles so there is no potential part contributing to the energy, only the kinetic energy of the particles.